# Using the enumerate function, is there a way to reference the index without also referencing the element?

Tags: python

I need to write a function that receives an array of integers and returns an array consisting of the product of all numbers in the array except the number at that index

For example, given:

```
[3, 7, 3, 4]
```

The function should return:

```
[84, 36, 84, 63]
```

By calculating:

```
[7*3*4, 3*3*4, 3*7*4, 3*7*3]
```

The function that I've written will work if the array contains no duplicates, but I can't seem to figure out how to reference skipping the index without also skipping any number in the array with the same value as the index.

```
def product_of_all_other_numbers(arr):
     product_array = []
     for idx, val in enumerate(arr):
         running_count = 1
         for n in arr:
             if n != arr[idx]:
                 running_count *= n
         product_array.append(running_count)
     return product_array
```

Is this possible with enumerate or should I start exploring a different route?

Comment: Please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions... python-3 is mainly assumed nowadays, since Python 3 pretty much *is* Python, at this point Python 2 is well passed it's end of life, is no longer officially supported, and has reach legacy status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't seem to figure out how to reference skipping the index without
> also skipping any number in the array with the same value as the
> index.

There's *no need* to compare the *values at that index*, you *only care about the index*. So your inner loop could be like this:

```
def product_of_all_other_numbers(arr):
     product_array = []
     for idx, val in enumerate(arr):
         running_count = 1
         for i, n in enumerate(arr):
             if i != idx:
                 running_count *= n
         product_array.append(running_count)
     return product_array
```

Note, there are more efficient solutions to this problem, but this addresses your current issue.

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for my ignorance, i'm still pretty new to this and unfortunately it's how my brain was able to work through the problem. Appreciate your help, will explore trying to find a more efficient solution.

Comment: @JustaphishintheC no need to apologize. Just keep practicing, these sorts of problems exist to help you learn how to approach other problems in the future. If you found this answer helpful, make sure to upvote and accept

Comment: "Note, there are more efficient solutions to this problem" - particularly, multiplying all the elements once up front and then *dividing* out individual elements from the overall product is much faster.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica well don't spoil it :)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Funny enough that's how I attacked this problem originally, but they ask us to try finding a solution without using division. Definitely appreciate any/all advice though!

Answer (score 2):

You could use numpy `prod` method and list slicing

```
In [91]: import math
In [92]: def product_of_all_other_numbers(lst):
    ...:     data = []
    ...:     for i in range(len(lst)):
    ...:         data.append(math.prod(lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]))
    ...:     return data
    ...:

In [93]: product_of_all_other_numbers([3, 7, 3, 4])
Out[93]: [84, 36, 84, 63]
```

Comment: this isn't a bad approach, but using numpy is overkill for a simple problem like this. In any case, in Python 3.8 you can use `import math; math.prod(whatever)` with no gargantuan third-party dependancy.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `math.prod` was introduced in version 3.8.

Comment: This is a cool solution! Could definitely use some brushing up on numpy, so many libraries / functions, will definitely keep this in mind going forward. Tried to upvote but i'm still too new to stackoverflow

Comment: @JustaphishintheC I upvoted your question, so you should be able to upvote now

Comment: @bigbounty im still at 13 reputation, hopefully soon I can repay the kindness

Comment: @JustaphishintheC Some good folk upvoted. Now you can upvote